# Error with load test and regular expressions - WSO2

Tags: java, wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

I have a RECEIVER that received a string:

```
Eventtype=2
Machineuserid={e5abyyef-t0dc-8wve-udxp-593z3swpbs10}
Datetime=2016-7-15 9:30:57.000 -0500
Licensekey=WxyzChXjhJ-dgjfZfHnL9-bWd4e2vxjD-eIs5hDu0To-VOxL111BAj
Version=4.1.3
Data=http://www.easysol.net/|53.70.16.07
Extradata=NA
OS=win64
OSVersion=6.1
```

My stream has a atributte of String Type:

```
{
  "name": "DATOS",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "nickName": "",
  "description": "",
  "metaData": [
    {
      "name": "DATA",
      "type": "STRING"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using a regular expresion for charge my string in the atributte DATA of my stream DATOS. My regular expresion is the next "([^;]+)":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eventReceiver name="httpdatos" statistics="disable" trace="disable" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventreceiver">
    <from eventAdapterType="http">
        <property name="transports">all</property>
    </from>
    <mapping customMapping="enable" type="text">
        <property>
            <from regex="([^;]+)"/>
            <to name="meta_DATA" type="string"/>
        </property>
    </mapping>
    <to streamName="DATOS" version="1.0.0"/>
</eventReceiver>
```

But my problem is when I make load testing and after of 200 threads I get the next error:

```
org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.ExecutionPlanRuntimeException: Cannot Execute Insert/Update. Null value detected for attributemeta_DATA
```

Can you help me please.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in DAS 3.0.1 and issue occurs due to RDBMS event table update/insert when having a null value for String attribute of an event. It is fixed in next DAS 3.1.0 release.. See [1] for more info..

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DAS-479